# The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.JavaScriptUtils' threw an exception

Tags: json, xamarin, serialization, xamarin.forms, json.net

I am having problems deserialising JSON into its corresponding C# Object.

My server returns valid JSON: `{"success":false,"message":"Please enter a valid Email Address."}`

My server is using a Laravel project and code to return JSON is:

```
return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address.']);
```

The error given is "The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.JavaScriptUtils' threw an exception."

This happens with various versions of Newtonsoft.Json, including the latest (11.0.2) and going back as far as 7.0.1. Didn't have this error before but I have updated Xamarin Forms today (3.0.0.550146).

Exception info here: https://pastebin.com/GWPJdj6T
Line 81 is call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

```
public class RegisterResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Messsage { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<string> RequestAccessCode(string email) {
    try {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress + requestAccess, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email.Trim())
            }));

            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisterResponse>(responseContent);
            return result.Messsage;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
            return exception.FormatExceptionInfo(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if your responseContent has data when you DeserializeObject?

Comment: Yep, responseContent is '{"success":false,"message":"Please enter a valid Email Address."}'

Comment: I have just tried running my app on the iOS Simulator and it's working fine... So I'm now wondering if it's down to iOS versions, my iPad is 10.3.1 and Simulator 11.4...

Comment: Also posted here https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1737 as still haven't been able to fix unfortunately.

Comment: The issue appears to only occur when the Debug profile is selected, but I have changed the settings to match those of Ad-Hoc (which works fine) except from using LLVM as it is not allowed for Debug.